# Wordpress footer in header when viewed in IE

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer

Well I cant figure this one out, it looks fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari etc... But when viewed in internet explorer 9 and earlier the footer plonks itself in the header of my [website](http://www.digitalcables.co.nz).

I've gone through and fixed a few W3C validation errors, messed around with the structure of the html, played around with the css as far as my knowledge allows, and read every related problem I could find. But all I have managed to do is break it in Firefox while it remains in the header in IE.

I also notice that not all of the corners of the midbar and content are rounding correctly, which may be related?

Comment: Your main content (Products page and sidebar) is part of <header> tag. Can you move it outside of header?

Comment: Thanks @rt2800, that was most of the problem, removing the CSS height as suggested below made it render correctly. Bonus questions for anyone still here: I can understand why it should be done this way, but what I don't understand is why then does this work fine when not using IE? And why the hell would the theme author do it this way in the first place?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the content inside your `<header>` tag and you've got a CSS `height`of `80px` for your header.

Try:
Get the content outside the `<header>`

Change

```
<header>...</header>
<footer>...</footer>
```

to

```
<header>...</header>
<div class="content">...</div>
<footer>...</footer>
```

AND
don't set the header's height

Comment: Fantastic, works great now thanks. I must have tried that at some stage but dismissed it since it messed everything up - but I didn't think to remove the 80px height as well! Removing the -moz and -webkit gradients fixed the rounded corners too.